# Physical Pixels vs CSS Pixels vs Device Independent Pixels vs Density Independent Pixels vs PPI

Tags: html, css

I am learning web development and I am having a hard time determining what is equivalent in all of this.

I know hardware pixels and physical pixels are the smallest unit, and that density independent pixels map to actual hardware pixels via a device pixel ratio and they are used to make the viewing experience more consistent.  Does this mean that the device independent pixels I'm seeing are the same thing?

Further, I read that the browser reports viewport width in CSS pixels, are these and DIPs the same thing?

I know that Pixels per inch are literal, they are the number of pixels in an inch, but how do they relate to DIPs? A totally separate measurement? When should I use that instead?

I hope this is an appropriate question, I am having issues mentally linking all of these concepts into one usable map, and didn't find any other question where they are all addressed at once.

Answer (score 18):

> I know hardware pixels and physical pixels are the smallest unit, and that density independent pixels map to actual hardware pixels via a device pixel ratio and they are used to make the viewing experience more consistent. Does this mean that the device independent pixels I'm seeing are the same thing?
>
> Further, I read that the browser reports viewport width in CSS pixels, are these and DIPs the same thing?

Yes on both counts. For example, an element with `height: 200px; width: 200px` is *always* 200 by 200 in DIPs or CSS pixels, even if the hardware is configured to display at a higher or lower resolution than usual. At a scale factor of 200%, if a 1x1 DIP or CSS pixel maps to a 1x1 physical pixel in 100%, it will map to a 2x2 physical pixel square.

> I know that Pixels per inch are literal, they are the number of pixels in an inch, but how do they relate to DIPs? A totally separate measurement?

CSS does not use PPI; it only uses DPI. [Section 6.4 of css-values-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#resolution) lists the following units:

> **dpi**
> Dots per inch.
>
> **dpcm**
> Dots per centimeter.
>
> **dppx**
> Dots per px unit.
>
> The <resolution> unit represents the size of a single "dot" in a graphical representation by indicating how many of these dots fit in a CSS in, cm, or px.

For the purposes of CSS and [Media Queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution0), a single "dot" always corresponds to a single physical pixel, never a DIP or CSS pixel, hence the dppx unit. For example, a scale factor of 200% or device pixel ratio (non-standard) of 2.0 is equivalent to 2 dppx.

Comment: Which should mean that for example Google Analytics reports CSS pixels, which are scaled according to the systems current scale factor?

For example: A screen resolution of 1440x900 can either be a screen with that physical resolution (1440x900) or 2880x1800 (in case of a 2x retina display) - am I understanding it correctly?