# why 1px seems larger on retina display?

Tags: html, css, devicepixelratio

I encountered this issue the 1px border looks 2px on retina display, I know it's something related to devicePixelRatio, but still don't get WHY.

**And if 1px looks 2px on retina display with a devicePixelRatio of 2, why the 200px*200px image doesn't look like 400px*400px?**

Any my second questions is, if I draw a box with width of 375px on iphone 6(375*667), it only takes half of the screen. Why?

Comment: Because the screen viewing distance is different, depending on the use of each device, the number of pixels per inch (PPI) defined as a retina can vary, depending on the display size, with higher pixel density on smaller screens and lower screen sizes.

Comment: Also you can read here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display

Comment: @לבנימלכה sorry, i didn't specify. i meant iphone 8 whose devicepixelratio is 2.

Comment: can you show your css code?

Comment: @לבנימלכה i believe it is a known issue, not related to how the code is written.

Comment: Per-pixel stuff in web technologies was developed in the 1990s, before high resolution displays were a thing. When 300dpi+ displays become mainstream backwards compatibility had to be kept—you want to be able to see 16x16 icons or 12px fonts in your ultra-expensive gadget!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physical Pixels vs CSS Pixels vs Device Independent Pixels vs Density Independent Pixels vs PPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863545/physical-pixels-vs-css-pixels-vs-device-independent-pixels-vs-density-independen)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't see the link actually cleared the doubts

Comment: Please check "an element with height: 200px; width: 200px is always 200 by 200 in DIPs or CSS pixels" and "CSS does not use PPI; it only uses DPI."

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález but why 1px looks thicker? If that's due to the fact 1px is mapped to two physical pixel, why 200px*200px don't look larger?

Comment: 200 CSS pixels are mapped to 400 physical pixels to look the same. Why do you think in should look *larger*? The whole point of Retina displays is to pack more tiny light cells in the same space.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález then why 1px doesn't look the same?

Comment: Is there a chance that you edit the question and post a sample snippet (maybe with a smaller picture, let's say 50x50, so it fits the display area) together with a screenshot? There's clearly something I'm not grasping.

Comment: I see you've added a second question. That depends on zoom level and viewport settings; it's in fact a slightly different subject. I assumed your original question refers to raw HTML at 100% zoom.