# Why don't some browser engines let me have 100.1px?

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Why do some browser engines not calculate fractional pixels precisely? Based on what logic these final values (.094, .188, .297 etc) are calculated? Is there any documentation for that?

Tested in **Chrome 100.0.4896.127** (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="width:100.1px">Hi</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Browsers don't respect fractional `px` values, so it's expected to see different behaviors on different browsers. Chrome and edge are using similar render engines, and that's why you are saying similar results on them (they might also differ if edge or chrome have done customizations to the render engine).

I think what is actually happening is that they are rounding values to the nearest **real pixel**. `1px` in CSS doesn't translate to 1 pixel on the screen ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863545/physical-pixels-vs-css-pixels-vs-device-independent-pixels-vs-density-independen)).

There is also another related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected).

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, browsers have different rendering engines that process and compute the styles. Try as they might, they might to get as close to the standard specifications as possible, their implementations are different. So they compute the pixel values differently.

Edge and Chrome are based off chromium rendering engine, while Firefox uses their own rendering engine as Amir said.